# Why does my IF STATEMENT result display but my ELSE STATEMENT also runs?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Am pulling out my hairs trying to figure this out...

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$template = $_GET['templateID'];
$campaign = $_GET['campaignID'];

// Grab everything in the campaign manager
$cm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campaign_manager WHERE campaign ='$campaign'") or die(mysql_error());

while($temp = mysql_fetch_array($cm)){
    //Checks if Template is already attached
    if($temp['paragraph'] == $template){
        echo 'Template is already attached - <a href="http://general:8888/templates">Back</a>';
    } else {
        if($temp['paragraph'] == '0' || $temp['paragraph'] == null ){
            mysql_query("UPDATE campaign_manager SET paragraph = '$template' WHERE campaign = '$campaign'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        else {
            $geo = $temp['geo'];
            $list = $temp['list'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO campaign_manager(campaign,paragraph,geo,list) VALUES('$campaign','$template','$geo','$list')");
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

My first IF is checking for a DUP. If it isn't it, it then checks if the field is either 0 or NULL. If THAT CHECK outs THEN it should add a new record into the 'campaign manager'. Although currently its displaying the echo of the first IF & its adding the duplicate record into the campaign manager. Why & HOW is this happening?

Comment: Is there any chance you have multiple rows in the table with the same `campaign` ID?

Comment: huge hole for [sql injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) there

Comment: @andrew medico : Yes, the table is a transaction table. So there will be many rows with the same campaign ID. But my IF statements should kill the loop once it finds a row with the SAME campaign id & paragraph id.

Comment: @tttony : The app is on a local environment.

Comment: @Mikulas Dite : I tried that, it still added the DUP.

Comment: You must add `break;` to where you want to cut off the loop.

Comment: @juhana I added the `break;` it didn't work BUT to add to the complexity of the issue.  The first record in the table will not DUP but anything after the first record WILL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, so after rethinking my code over the weekend. I came up with this...

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$template = $_GET['templateID'];
$campaign = $_GET['campaignID'];

// Grab everything in the campaign manager
$cm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campaign_manager WHERE campaign ='$campaign'") or die(mysql_error());
$match = 0;

while($temp = mysql_fetch_array($cm)){
    if ($temp['paragraph'] == $template){
        echo 'Template is already attached - <a href="http://general:8888/templates">Back</a>';
        $match = 1;
    }
}

$geo = $temp['geo'];
$list = $temp['list'];

if ($match == 0){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO campaign_manager(campaign,paragraph,geo,list) VALUES('$campaign','$template','$geo','$list')");
    header('Location: http://general:8888/templates/');
}

?>
```

It works finally.

Answer (score 2):

It is in a while loop, is it at all possible that that is causing the problem?
Two records could easily cause it to echo and update.

Check through your code to see if the page refreshes as well.

Comment: The while loop should be terminated based off my IF / Else statements. Shouldn't it?

Comment: How so? I don't see anything that would kill the loop if there were multiple records returned.

Comment: On my first iteration, My IF statement `if($temp['paragraph'] == $template)` is explicitly checking if the current row has a DUP in the paragraph column. If it is DUPPED, it would execute `echo 'Template is already attached - <a href="http://general:8888/templates">Back</a>';` and run through the loop again and NOT touch the ELSE statement. My problem is that it's executing BOTH IF and ELSE. To add to the complexity of the problem. It will not duplicate my first record but it will DUP anything after the first rec.

Comment: From what I can see from the code your provided, if `mysql_fetch_array($cm)` returns 2 (or more) rows, it has the possibility to both echo and update. It will NOT echo and update at the same time, but rather 2 different times. Try to echo `$temp` name in the `echo` statement to see if this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is simply not possible. You've got probably this part of code somewhere and it is causing 2 executes

Comment: Not possible? The code is inside a loop. It executes as many times as the loop runs.

Comment: It's probably just speculation on the OP's part if he assumed that the select query always returns only one result.

Comment: The while loop should only go through the number iterations based off the number of rows that result from $cm query. It should then go through the IF statement checks. The part that has me stumped is how can it display the IF & execute the ELSE. If it were looping again, then shouldn't one of the IF checks end the loop?

Comment: @Daniel no. It goes to ifstatement everytime

Comment: @genesis Right but, if goes to the IF statement. The IF statement it should should keep it from doing both. Maybe am not following your train of thought correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try a few things:

First you have a lot of security flaws here so I do not recommend anyone use the code above in the form its in because of potential XSS and SQL injection flaws. You are passing parameters from 'GET' and putting it right into your query value.

The proper way of doing this is searchable here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Also PHP SQLi prevetion through PDO (preferred) or mysql_real_escape is found in the php.net manual by doing a simple google search for MySQL PDO.

... grr php...

Ok next, Your branching logic is a bit flawed. Lets break it down to work on it.

```
if($temp['paragraph'] == $template){
        echo 'Template is already attached - <a href="templates">Back</a>';
 } elseif ($temp['paragraph'] == '0') {
            mysql_query("UPDATE campain_manager SET paragraph = '$template' WHERE campaign  = $campain'") or die(mysql_error()); 
 }
   elseif ($temp['paragraph'] == null ){
            mysql_query("UPDATE campaign_manager SET paragraph = '$template' WHERE campaign = '$campaign'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
else 
{ $geo = $temp['geo'];
            $list = $temp['list'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO campaign_manager(campaign,paragraph,geo,list) VALUES('$campaign','$template','$geo','$list')");
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Now I am not a developer by trade, this to many doesn't feel correct, I think you can potentially re-factor your code and make it smaller. I would also try and make it more functional if you could. By the way I didn't have time to correct all of these issues above, let me tell you, the code I have above is also vulnerable. To properly correct it , replace mysql_query with mysql_real_escape_string. Also make sure you are not just grabbing input from the user and:

A) Improperly sanitizing it,
B) Improperly outputting it.

Do not trust all client-side code, validation on the server is trusted. Don't deliver your server side code client side.

HTH

M